# Find integer solutions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Find all integer solutions to the following:

$2x+10y-11z=1$
$x-6y+14z=2$

I am not quite sure how to do this... I know I will get equations in the end with each variable expressed in terms of another variable, but I'm not sure how to get to that point.

Comment: @Sarah Start by solving for one variable. I'd recommend beginning with solving for $x$ in the second equation.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT:** Try to make the equation have only 2 variables on either side of the equation.

For example, multiply the 2nd equation by 2.
$2x-12y+28z=4$
Now take this away from the 1st equation:
$22y-39z=-3$
Rearrange:
$22y+3=39z$